# Selenium Python sel.click("css=input.smthg")?

Tags: python, css, selenium, click

I am writing a script in Python for Selenium but the action "sel.click" doesn't work when the selection is a CSS :

```
def test_test_remote(self):
    sel = self.selenium
    sel.open("/fr")
    sel.click("id=flightFrom")
    sel.type("id=flightFrom", "Londres-Stansted")
    sel.type("id=flightTo", "Dublin")
    sel.click("id=termsAccept")
    sel.click("css=input.bookFlightButton") ----> nothing happens
    sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Regards.

Vincent

Comment: could you possibly provide the HTML source, this could be an issue as mentioned below regarding javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by behind-the-scenes Javascript code. Probably when you navigate the website with your browser, you can just click the element, and everything works as expected. Say that `input.bookFlightButton` actually handles the submit request on its `mouseup` handler for example: your `click` command could fail on that.

Two things I would try. First, check if you can't submit your form with Selenium's `Submit Form` command. With some luck, this will give you the result you want.

For the other thing, you'll have to poke in the Javascript a little. If the site happens to use jQuery, start a command window in your browser (Chrome has this by default; for Firefox you need Firebug, IE... no idea). Then try to toggle the form submission by using jQuery:

```
$('input.bookFlightButton').click()
$('input.bookFlightButton').mouseup()
```

When you've found the call that works, replace the `sel.click` on that button with something along the following lines:

```
sel.get_eval("window.jQuery('input.bookFlightButton').mouseup()")
```

...to toggle it from Selenium.